# Wie man "You'll never make me (talk/do something/work/etc)" auf Deutsch sagt

Tags: vocabulary

Zum Beispiel, würde man

> "Du wirst mich nie dazu bringen, zu reden"

sagen, oder eher

> "Du wirst mich nie zum Reden bringen"

?

Oder würde man eher das Verb "zwingen" benutzen?

> "Du wirst mich nie zum Reden zwingen"
>
> "Du wirst mich nie zu zwingen, zu reden"

Comment: This question appears to be a bit unclear to me. Both your examples are valid, the second sounding better, but neither seems to show what your question is really about.

Comment: "You'll never (be able to) make me say anything!"

Comment: Der erwieterte Infinitiv mit "zu" klingt für mich in dem Fall nicht gut, da er zu kurz ist. Es sollte etwas mehr Substanz da sein als nur "zu" und das Verb. Zum Beispiel: *Du wirst mich nie dazu bringen, über vergangene Liebschaften zu reden.* Hiengegen würde  *Du wirst mich nie zum Reden über vergangene Liebschaften bringen.* für mein Gefühl ungeschickt klingen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a question of context: "Du wirst mich nie dazu bringen, zu reden" is something that would be fitting in a context where the speaker is calm but wants to be absolute clear that he never will be talking.
"Du wirst mich nie zum Reden bringen can be used in the same Situation but isn't quite as powerful, also it is fitting when screaming at someone in anger or while being tortured.

"Du wirst mich nie zum Reden zwingen" as well as the last one is the same as the previous, the change of the word "bringen" to the word "zwingen" at the end would be likely due local customary behaviour.

Much more uncommon but still done, especially in literature and movies:
The change between "zwingen" and "bringen" can change the meaning of the sentence.
The following sentence:"Du wirst mich nicht zum reden zwingen, aber für ein kleines Sümmchen könnte ich dir etwas verraten"

English: "You can't force me to talk, but for a small amount of money, I could tell you some things."
In this case it is not so much about the talking but the ability to force someone to talk, "bringen" can't be used in this way.

But only if you have the context, we be able to tell you how exactly it is meant or to be used.

Comment: Was die ersten 2 Abschnitte betrifft würde ich sagen, dass das doch sehr von der Betonung abhängt.

Comment: Stimmt, das wollte ich mit dem Beispiel einer Situation deutlich machen, dass das eine eine Verdeutlichung in einem ruhigen Gespräch ist, die auch einiges an Nachdruck hat und das andere eher üblich as eventuell sogar dramatisierter Ausruf.